# Nested Function Returns Unexpected Result

Tags: reactjs

I have a menu component in my header component. The header component passes a function to the menu component => default menu component. It's working but the function returns unwanted data.

the path my function is traveling through is:
homepage => header => menu => defaultMenu

The function is:

```
changeBodyHandler = (newBody) => {
    console.log(newBody)
    this.setState({
      body: newBody
    })
}
```

I pass the function from homepage => header like this:

```
<HeaderDiv headerMenuClick={() => this.changeBodyHandler}/>
```

then through header => menu => defaultMenu using:

```
<Menu MenuClick={this.props.headerMenuClick} />
```

//==================== COMPONENT CODES ==========================//

homepage:

```
class Homepage extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            body: "Homepage"
        }

    this.changeBodyHandler = this.changeBodyHandler.bind(this)
    }

    changeBodyHandler = (newBody) => {
        console.log(newBody)
        this.setState({
            body: newBody
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <HeaderDiv headerMenuClick={() => this.changeBodyHandler}/>
            { this.state.body === "Homepage" ?
              <HomepageBody />
              :  (<div> </div>)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

header:

```
class HeaderDiv extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          showMenu: 'Default',
      }
  }

    render(){
      return (
                <Menu MenuClick={this.props.headerMenuClick}/>
      );
    }
}
```

menu:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DefaultMenu from './SubCompMenu/DefaultMenu';
import LoginCom from './SubCompMenu/LoginCom';
import SingupCom from './SubCompMenu/SingupCom';

class Menu extends Component {
//==================================================================
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: this.props.shows
    };
    this.getBackCancelLoginForm = this.getBackCancelLoginForm.bind(this);
  }
//===============================================================
//getBackCancelLoginForm use to hindle click event singin & singup childs
//===============================================================
  getBackCancelLoginForm(e){
    console.log("Hi")
      this.setState({
          show : "Default"
      })
  }
//=================================================================
// getDerivedStateFromProps changes state show when props.shows changes
//===============================================================
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if(this.props.show != this.nextProps){
      this.setState({ show: nextProps.shows });
  }
}
//======================================================================
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.show === "Singin" ?
          <LoginCom
            cencelLogin={this.getBackCancelLoginForm.bind(this)}
          />
        : (<div> </div>)}

        { this.state.show === "Singup" ?
          <SingupCom
            cencelLogin={this.getBackCancelLoginForm.bind(this)}
          />
        : (<div> </div>)}

        { this.state.show === "Default" ?
          <DefaultMenu MenuClicks={this.props.MenuClick}/> : (<div> </div>)}

      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Default menu:

```
class DefaultMenu extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <div className="box11" onClick={this.props.MenuClicks("Homepage")}>
            <h3 className="boxh3" onClick={this.props.MenuClicks("Homepage")}>HOME</h3>

    );
  }
}
```

//================ Describe expected and actual results. ================//

I'm expecting the string "Homepage" to be assigned to my state "body"

but `console.log` shows:

```
Class {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, nativeEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", target: div.box11, …}
```

instead of "Homepage"

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow functions in onClick listener, in above question Change `DefaultMenu` as:

```
class DefualtMenu extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
            <div className="box11" onClick={() => this.props.MenuClicks("Homepage")}>
              <h3 className="boxh3">HOME</h3>
            </div>
      );
    } }
```

For arrow functions learn from [mozilla Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

I hope this helps.